# jQuery draggable containment custom shape

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, bounds, containment

I want to dragg a object with the red lines as bounderies. (check image below)

I looked for examples but all i can find are square and circualar shapes.

- i tried a element with css transform rotate attachted to it -> didn't
  work
- i tried svg shape -> not supported
- i tried to make a shape with canvas - didn't work

i ran out of idea's so hope one of you have one

[image: Containment of object in red]

Comment: any possible way you can provide a fiddle or running code snippit

Comment: jQuery draggables interact with elements in the dom, which are laid out rectangularly, if you want to drag shapes that aren't regular dom objects why are you using jQuery draggables?

Comment: Are the shapes dynamic? Could you have transparent rectangular images that represent the shapes and drag them? What have you tried with with canvas?

Comment: @StuperUser yesh, the object i want to drag is a image with transparent background. what i want is to create a scene where i can drag the image around. so the dragged object is a square but the ground/floor is a shape.

Comment: You could create a helper to see if a point is inside a given shape (defined as a set of point coordinates), then use that to validate after dragging or bound the area while dragging.